# What affixes are available on items?

Tags: diablo-iii

What affixes (prefixes and suffixes) are possible on items in Diablo III?  What are the level requirements associated with them (a.k.a. when would I start seeing them drop or available in a store?)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are different magnitudes of identically named effects so a level range of affixes doesn't make the most sense, since the "level" of the affix can vary, and it is much more important *what* it appears on. If you want to know the individual tiers in addition to which affixes appear on what, check this link [here](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/).

I've listed the affixes below, by slot. I.e., all affixes in the **Weapon** slot can appear on any weapon, but **Crossbow** affixes can't appear on Swords or Daggers. Affixes increase in magnitude from left to right. e.g. Low/Medium/High/Ultra

Some affixes are different magnitudes when they appear on different item classes. These are listed as (Tier I), (Tier II), or (Tier III), with Tier I being the best, and Tier III being the (relative) worst. For instance, *Reflect Damage* can show up on any  piece of armor as Tier II, but on a shield, it might also be Tier I. The exact difference between the tiers depends on the affix in question. Again, see the link above for the full story. Finally, note that even items elligible for Tier I may roll a lower tier if the random numbers are poor.

The original source from this is the Brady Games Strategy Guide, so it may still be incomplete.

(This list is from the Brady Games strategy guide, and may be incomplete)

**Armor**

- *+ Armor (Tier II)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *+% Experience per Kill* - Adventuring / Clever / Restless / Savvy
- *+% Gold Find (Tier II)* - Lucky / Glittering / Prosperous
- *+ Gold Pickup Radius (Tier II)* - Gathering / Greedy / Miserly / Avaricious
- *Health Globe Bonus* - Mending / Invigorating / Renewing / Euphoric
- *+ Life Regen per Second (Tier II)* - Reptillian / Salubrious / Undying / Immortal
- *+% Magic Find (Tier II)* - Scouting / Ransacking / Seeking
- *Reflect Damage (Tier II)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors
- *+ Strength (Tier II)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier II)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier II)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier II)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory
- *+ Strength and Dexterity (Tier II)* - Cruel / Severe / Vicious / Murderous
- *+ Strength and Intelligence (Tier II)* - Dueling / Champion / Triumphant / Paragon
- *+ Strength and Vitality (Tier II)* - Dauntless / Relentless / Vigorous / Ruthless
- *+ Dexterity and Intelligence (Tier II)* - True / Steadfast / Worthy / Marvelous
- *+ Dexterity and Vitality (Tier II)* - Feral / Wild / Potent / Valiant
- *+ Intelligence and Vitality (Tier II)* - Proud / Vaunted / Glorious / Illustrious

**Amulet**

- *+ Armor (Tier I)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *% Blind on hit (Tier I)* - Dazzling / Bewildering / Perplexing / Hypnotic
- *+% Chance to Block (Tier II)* - of the Tortoise / of Deflection / of Interception / of Invulnerability
- *+% Critical Hit Chance (Tier I)* - Iron / Sawtooth / Lacerating / Flaying
- *+% Critical Hit Damage (Tier I)* - Brutal / Wicked / Deadly / Merciless
- *+% Gold Find (Tier I)* - Lucky / Glittering / Prosperous
- *+ Gold Pickup Radius (Tier I)* - Gathering / Greedy / Miserly / Avaricious
- *Health Globe Bonus* - Mending / Invigorating / Renewing / Euphoric
- *+% Increased Attack Speed (Tier II)* - Keen / Raiding / Assailing / Vanquishing
- *X Life on Hit (Tier I)* - of the Leech / of Carnage / of Gore / of Mangling
- *X Life on Kill (Tier I)* - of Slaughter/ of Mutilation/ of Extermination
- *+ Life Regen per Second (Tier I)* - Reptillian / Salubrious / Undying / Immortal
- *+% Magic Find (Tier I)* - Scouting / Ransacking / Seeking
- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier I)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier I)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier III)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death
- *+% Maximum Life (Tier I)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *Reflect Damage (Tier I)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors
- *Resist Physical* - Hardened / Hermetic / Untouchable
- *Resist Lightning* - Silent / Tranquil / Stable
- *Resist Fire* - Seared / Charred / Scorched
- *Resist Poison* - Pure / Untarnished / Pristine
- *Resist Cold* - Nomadic / Sheltering / Thawing
- *Resist All* - Spectral / Chromatic
- *+ Strength (Tier I)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier I)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier I)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier I)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory
- *+ Strength and Dexterity (Tier I)* - Cruel / Severe / Vicious / Murderous
- *+ Strength and Intelligence (Tier I)* - Dueling / Champion / Triumphant / Paragon
- *+ Strength and Vitality (Tier I)* - Dauntless / Relentless / Vigorous / Ruthless
- *+ Dexterity and Intelligence (Tier I)* - True / Steadfast / Worthy / Marvelous
- *+ Dexterity and Vitality (Tier I)* - Feral / Wild / Potent / Valiant
- *+ Intelligence and Vitality (Tier I)* - Proud / Vaunted / Glorious / Illustrious

**Belt**

- *+% Maximum Life (Tier II)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *% Freeze on Hit (Tier I)* - of Ice / of Hale / of the Frozen Sea / of Desolation
- *Reflect Damage (Tier I)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors
- *+ Strength (Tier I)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier I)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier I)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier I)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory
- *Hammer of the Ancients Bonus* - of Demolition
- *Weapon Throw Bonus* - of Hurling
- *Rend Bonus* - of Evisceration
- *Bash Bonus* - of Bruising
- *Whirlwind Bonus* - of Vertigo
- *Cleave Bonus* - of Sundering
- *Revenge Bonus* - of Vengeance
- *Frenzy Bonus* - of the Maniac

**Boots**

- *% Immobilize on Hit (Tier I)* - of Stagnation / of Impairment / of Sabotage / of Paralysis
- *+% Move Speed* - Quick / Nimble / Sounding / Swift / Fleet

**Bow**

- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier II)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier II)*  - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation

**Bracers**

- *+% Critical Hit Chance (Tier II)* - Iron / Sawtooth / Lacerating / Flaying
- *Damage Reduction vs. Missiles* - Deflecting
- *% Knockback on Hit (Tier I)* - Battering / Pummeling / Smashing / Pulverizing

**Chest Armor**

- *+ Armor (Tier I)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *Damage Reduction vs. Melee* - of the Gladiator
- *Damage Reduction vs. Missiles* - Deflecting
- *+ Life Regen per Second (Tier I)* - Reptillian / Salubrious / Undying / Immortal
- *+% Maximum Life (Tier II)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *Reflect Damage (Tier I)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors

**Ceremonial Knife**

- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier II)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death
- *+Max Mana* - Bewitching / Conjuring / Mesmerizing / Unearthly
- *+Mana Regen* - Infusing / Replenishing / Energizing / Intensifying

**Cloak**

- *+Hatred Regen* - Spiteful / Bitter / Hostile / Vengeful
- *+Maximum Discipline* - Steady / Confident

**Dagger**

- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier III)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage(Tier III)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death

**Daibo**

- *+Spirit Regen* - Illuminating / Reborn / Awakening / Enlightening
- *Sprit Spent Heals X* - Resonant / Rejuvenating / Harmonious / Exalted

**Fist Weapon**

- *+Spirit Regen* - Illuminating / Reborn / Awakening / Enlightening
- *Sprit Spent Heals X* - Resonant / Rejuvenating / Harmonious / Exalted

**Follower Special**

- *+% Critical Hit Damage (Tier I)* - Brutal / Wicked / Deadly / Merciless
- *X Life on Hit (Tier I)* - of the Leech / of Carnage / of Gore / of Mangling
- *X Life on Kill (Tier I)* - of Slaughter/ of Mutilation/ of Extermination
- *+ Life Regen per Second (Tier I)* - Reptillian / Salubrious / Undying / Immortal
- *Resist Physical* - Hardened / Hermetic / Untouchable
- *Resist Lightning* - Silent / Tranquil / Stable
- *Resist Fire* - Seared / Charred / Scorched
- *Resist Poison* - Pure / Untarnished / Pristine
- *Resist Cold* - Nomadic / Sheltering / Thawing
- *Resist All* - Spectral / Chromatic
- *+ Strength (Tier I)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier I)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier I)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier I)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory
- *+ Strength and Dexterity (Tier I)* - Cruel / Severe / Vicious / Murderous
- *+ Strength and Intelligence (Tier I)* - Dueling / Champion / Triumphant / Paragon
- *+ Strength and Vitality (Tier I)* - Dauntless / Relentless / Vigorous / Ruthless
- *+ Dexterity and Intelligence (Tier I)* - True / Steadfast / Worthy / Marvelous
- *+ Dexterity and Vitality (Tier I)* - Feral / Wild / Potent / Valiant
- *+ Intelligence and Vitality (Tier I)* - Proud / Vaunted / Glorious / Illustrious

**Gloves**

- *+% Critical Hit Chance (Tier I)* - Iron / Sawtooth / Lacerating / Flaying
- *+% Critical Hit Damage (Tier II)* - Brutal / Wicked / Deadly / Merciless
- *+% Increased Attack Speed (Tier II)* - Keen / Raiding / Assailing / Vanquishing
- *% Stun on Hit (Tier I)* - of Striking / of Bane / of Ruin / of Devastation

**Hand Crossbow**

- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier III)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier III)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death
- *+Hatred Regen* - Spiteful / Bitter / Hostile / Vengeful
- *+Maximum Discipline* - Steady / Confident

**Helm**

- *+ Armor (Tier I)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *+% Critical Hit Chance (Tier II)* - Iron / Sawtooth / Lacerating / Flaying
- *+% Maximum Life (Tier II)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *% Fear on Hit (Tier I)* - of Fright / of Nightmares / of Horror / of Terror

**Jewelry**

- *+% Experience per Kill* - Adventuring / Clever / Restless / Savvy

**Mighty Belt**

- *Steal % Life on Hit* - Vampiric / Fiendish / Gruesome / Exsanguinating
- *+ Maximum Fury* - Reckless / Wrathful
- *Hammer of the Ancients Bonus* - of Demolition
- *Weapon Throw Bonus* - of Hurling
- *Rend Bonus* - of Evisceration
- *Bash Bonus* - of Bruising
- *Whirlwind Bonus* - of Vertigo
- *Cleave Bonus* - of Sundering
- *Revenge Bonus* - of Vengeance
- *Frenzy Bonus* - of the Maniac

**Mojo**

- *+Max Mana* - Bewitching / Conjuring / Mesmerizing / Unearthly
- *+Mana Regen* - Infusing / Replenishing / Energizing / Intensifying

**Offhand**

- *% Blind on hit (Tier II)* - Dazzling / Bewildering / Perplexing / Hypnotic
- *% Chill on hit (Tier II)* - Chilling / Sleek / Glacial / Hyperborean
- *+% Critical Hit Chance (Tier I)* - Iron / Sawtooth / Lacerating / Flaying
- *+% Experience per Kill* - Adventuring / Clever / Restless / Savvy
- *% Fear on Hit (Tier II)* - of Fright / of Nightmares / of Horror / of Terror
- *% Freeze on Hit (Tier II)* - of Ice / of Hale / of the Frozen Sea / of Desolation
- *+% Gold Find (Tier II)* - Lucky / Glittering / Prosperous
- *+ Gold Pickup Radius (Tier II)* - Gathering / Greedy / Miserly / Avaricious
- *Health Globe Bonus* - Mending / Invigorating / Renewing / Euphoric
- *% Immobilize on Hit (Tier II)* - of Stagnation / of Impairment / of Sabotage / of Paralysis
- *% Knockback on Hit (Tier II)* - Battering / Pummeling / Smashing / Pulverizing
- *+ Life Regen per Second (Tier II)* - Reptillian / Salubrious / Undying / Immortal
- *+% Magic Find (Tier II)* - Scouting / Ransacking / Seeking
- *+% Maximum Life (Tier II)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *Reflect Damage (Tier II)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors
- *% Slow on Hit (Tier II)* - Crippling / Punishing / Persecuting / Dominating
- *% Stun on Hit (Tier II)* - of Striking / of Bane / of Ruin / of Devastation
- *+ Strength (Tier II)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier II)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier II)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier II)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory
- *+ Strength and Dexterity (Tier II)* - Cruel / Severe / Vicious / Murderous
- *+ Strength and Intelligence (Tier II)* - Dueling / Champion / Triumphant / Paragon
- *+ Strength and Vitality (Tier II)* - Dauntless / Relentless / Vigorous / Ruthless
- *+ Dexterity and Intelligence (Tier II)* - True / Steadfast / Worthy / Marvelous
- *+ Dexterity and Vitality (Tier II)* - Feral / Wild / Potent / Valiant
- *+ Intelligence and Vitality (Tier II)* - Proud / Vaunted / Glorious / Illustrious

**Orb**

- *+Maximum Arcane Power* - Sly / Mental
- *+Arcane Power on Crit* - Foreboding / Ominous

**Pants**

- *+ Armor (Tier I)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *% Slow on Hit (Tier I)* - Crippling / Punishing / Persecuting / Dominating

**Polearm**

- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier II)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death
- *Overpower Bonus* - of Conquest
- *Seismic Slam Bonus* - of Shattering

**Quiver**

- *+Hatred Regen* - Spiteful / Bitter / Hostile / Vengeful
- *+Maximum Discipline* - Steady / Confident

**Ring**

- *+ Armor (Tier II)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *+% Critical Hit Chance (Tier II)* - Iron / Sawtooth / Lacerating / Flaying
- *+% Critical Hit Damage (Tier II)* - Brutal / Wicked / Deadly / Merciless
- *+% Gold Find (Tier II)* - Lucky / Glittering / Prosperous
- *+ Gold Pickup Radius (Tier II)* - Gathering / Greedy / Miserly / Avaricious
- *Health Globe Bonus* - Mending / Invigorating / Renewing / Euphoric
- *+% Increased Attack Speed (Tier II)* - Keen / Raiding / Assailing / Vanquishing
- *X Life on Hit (Tier II)* - of the Leech / of Carnage / of Gore / of Mangling
- *X Life on Kill (Tier II)* - of Slaughter/ of Mutilation/ of Extermination
- *+ Life Regen per Second (Tier II)* - Reptillian / Salubrious / Undying / Immortal
- *+% Magic Find (Tier II)* - Scouting / Ransacking / Seeking
- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier I)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier I)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier I)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death
- *+% Maximum Life (Tier II)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *Reflect Damage (Tier II)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors
- *Resist Physical* - Hardened / Hermetic / Untouchable
- *Resist Lightning* - Silent / Tranquil / Stable
- *Resist Fire* - Seared / Charred / Scorched
- *Resist Poison* - Pure / Untarnished / Pristine
- *Resist Cold* - Nomadic / Sheltering / Thawing
- *Resist All* - Spectral / Chromatic
- *+ Strength (Tier II)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier II)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier II)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier II)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory
- *+ Strength and Dexterity (Tier II)* - Cruel / Severe / Vicious / Murderous
- *+ Strength and Intelligence (Tier II)* - Dueling / Champion / Triumphant / Paragon
- *+ Strength and Vitality (Tier II)* - Dauntless / Relentless / Vigorous / Ruthless
- *+ Dexterity and Intelligence (Tier II)* - True / Steadfast / Worthy / Marvelous
- *+ Dexterity and Vitality (Tier II)* - Feral / Wild / Potent / Valiant
- *+ Intelligence and Vitality (Tier II)* - Proud / Vaunted / Glorious / Illustrious

**Shield**

- *+ Armor (Tier I)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *+% Chance to Block (Tier II)* - of the Tortoise / of Deflection / of Interception / of Invulnerability
- *Damage Reduction vs. Melee* - of the Gladiator
- *+% Maximum Life (Tier I)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *Reflect Damage (Tier II)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors
- *Resist Physical* - Hardened / Hermetic / Untouchable
- *Resist Lightning* - Silent / Tranquil / Stable
- *Resist Fire* - Seared / Charred / Scorched
- *Resist Poison* - Pure / Untarnished / Pristine
- *Resist Cold* - Nomadic / Sheltering / Thawing
- *Resist All* - Spectral / Chromatic
- *Overpower Bonus* - of Conquest
- *Seismic Slam Bonus* - of Shattering

**Shoulder Armor**

- *% Chill on hit (Tier I)* - Chilling / Sleek / Glacial / Hyperborean
- *+% Maximum Life (Tier II)* - Rugged / Stalwart
- *Reflect Damage (Tier II)* - of Thorns / of Barbs / of Spikes / of Razors
- *+ Strength (Tier I)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier I)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier I)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier I)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory

**Spear**

- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier II)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier I)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death

**Spirit Stone**

- *+Spirit Regen* - Illuminating / Reborn / Awakening / Enlightening
- *Sprit Spent Heals X* - Resonant / Rejuvenating / Harmonious / Exalted

**Templar Relic**

- *+ Armor (Tier I)* - of the Fortress / of the Castle
- *+% Chance to Block (Tier II)* - of the Tortoise / of Deflection / of Interception / of Invulnerability

**Voodoo Mask**

- *+Max Mana* - Bewitching / Conjuring / Mesmerizing / Unearthly
- *+Mana Regen* - Infusing / Replenishing / Energizing / Intensifying

**Wand**

- *+% Maximum Damage (Tier II)* - of Maiming / of Strife / of Doom
- *+% Minimum Damage (Tier II)* - of Destruction/ of Severing/ of Devastation
- *+% Maximum & Minimum Damage (Tier I)* - of Wounding / of Agony / of Malice / of Death
- *+Maximum Arcane Power* - Sly / Mental
- *+Arcane Power on Crit* - Foreboding / Ominous

**Weapon, One-Hand**

- *% Blind on hit (Tier II)* - Dazzling / Bewildering / Perplexing / Hypnotic
- *% Chill on hit (Tier II)* - Chilling / Sleek / Glacial / Hyperborean
- *% Fear on Hit (Tier II)* - of Fright / of Nightmares / of Horror / of Terror
- *% Freeze on Hit (Tier II)* - of Ice / of Hale / of the Frozen Sea / of Desolation
- *% Immobilize on Hit (Tier II)* - of Stagnation / of Impairment / of Sabotage / of Paralysis
- *% Knockback on Hit (Tier II)* - Battering / Pummeling / Smashing / Pulverizing
- *% Slow on Hit (Tier II)* - Crippling / Punishing / Persecuting / Dominating
- *% Stun on Hit (Tier II)* - of Striking / of Bane / of Ruin / of Devastation

**Weapon, Two-Hand**

- *% Blind on hit (Tier I)* - Dazzling / Bewildering / Perplexing / Hypnotic
- *% Chill on hit (Tier I)* - Chilling / Sleek / Glacial / Hyperborean
- *% Fear on Hit (Tier I)* - of Fright / of Nightmares / of Horror / of Terror
- *% Freeze on Hit (Tier I)* - of Ice / of Hale / of the Frozen Sea / of Desolation
- *% Immobilize on Hit (Tier I)* - of Stagnation / of Impairment / of Sabotage / of Paralysis
- *% Knockback on Hit (Tier I)* - Battering / Pummeling / Smashing / Pulverizing
- *% Slow on Hit (Tier I)* - Crippling / Punishing / Persecuting / Dominating
- *% Stun on Hit (Tier I)* - of Striking / of Bane / of Ruin / of Devastation
- *Overpower Bonus* - of Conquest
- *Seismic Slam Bonus* - of Shattering

**Weapon, Mighty**

- *+ Maximum Fury* - Reckless / Wrathful

**Weapon**

- *+% Critical Hit Damage (Tier I)* - Brutal / Wicked / Deadly / Merciless
- *+% Experience per Kill* - Adventuring / Clever / Restless / Savvy
- *+% Increased Attack Speed (Tier I)* - Keen / Raiding / Assailing / Vanquishing
- *X Life on Hit (Tier I)* - of the Leech / of Carnage / of Gore / of Mangling
- *X Life on Kill (Tier I)* - of Slaughter/ of Mutilation/ of Extermination
- *Steal % Life on Hit* - Vampiric / Fiendish / Gruesome / Exsanguinating
- *% More Damage* - Ferocious / Savage / Grim
- *+ Strength (Tier I)* - of the Lion / of Invasion / of Assault
- *+ Dexterity (Tier I)* - of the Hawk / of Cruelty / of Pain
- *+ Intelligence (Tier I)* - of Focus / of the Mind / of Omens / of Far Sight
- *+ Vitality (Tier I)* - of the Bear / of Fortitude / of Valor / of Glory
- *+ Strength and Dexterity (Tier I)* - Cruel / Severe / Vicious / Murderous
- *+ Strength and Intelligence (Tier I)* - Dueling / Champion / Triumphant / Paragon
- *+ Strength and Vitality (Tier I)* - Dauntless / Relentless / Vigorous / Ruthless
- *+ Dexterity and Intelligence (Tier I)* - True / Steadfast / Worthy / Marvelous
- *+ Dexterity and Vitality (Tier I)* - Feral / Wild / Potent / Valiant
- *+ Intelligence and Vitality (Tier I)* - Proud / Vaunted / Glorious / Illustrious

**Wizard Hat**

- *+Maximum Arcane Power* - Sly / Mental
- *+Arcane Power on Crit* - Foreboding / Ominous

Comment: Wow.  What was the source?

Comment: @stephen Check the first paragraph. The original source is the Brady Games Strategy guide, I believe.

Comment: Ah!  You can understand how I missed that given the size of the post.  Thanks!