# What pieces of armor can carry the increased attack speed attribute?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What affixes are available on items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67082/what-affixes-are-available-on-items)

What are all the pieces of armor that can carry the increased attack speed attribute?

I know gloves and amulets can, but what else?

Comment: For future reference: You can easily test this yourself by going to the auction house and fiddling with the affix filters. Only when an affix is actually available on an item it will show up in there.

Comment: @Xeo I've had trouble with the AH not displaying affix filters for items that should have that filter available (i.e. the item I'm selling has that affix...yet the AH doesn't allow me to filter by that affix for that type of item)

Answer (score 1):

The one's that I am aware of are as follows:

Amulet

Gloves

Rings

You weapon can also have attack speed increase, but its already calculated into the dps of the weapon, so it's not as usefull as the other slots.